# jquerymobile using Select menus with Ruby on Rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-mobile, view, nomethoderror

I have two models Promotions and Goods

when i create a promotion must associate it with a good, so in the view i used

```
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :good%><br />
  <%= f.text_field :good%>
  </div>
```

so i pointed out here the good's id for the association but the users don't know the id ,so i would show in a select menus the names of the goods to users and then do the association.

i think to use a for cicle but have an error in the view:

```
 <div class="field">

<label for="select-choice-0" class="select">Good</label>
<% @goods.each do |g| %>
<select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-0">
<option value="standard"><%=g.name %></option>
<%end%>
</select>
</div>
```

**NoMethodError in Promotions#new**
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each

how to solve this?

Comment: You have to load @goods variable which might be Good.all

Comment: I guess if you want drop down which shows a goods `<select name="promotions[good_id]" id="select-choice-0"><% @goods.each do |g| %><option value=<%=g.id%>><%=g.name %></option><% end %></select>`

Comment: so show me the ordes in select but when create a promotion good_id rest null in database so I have no association!

Comment: name="promotion[good_id]" Ok thanks :)

Comment: when write in the views <%=@goods=Good.all%> for have all goods in the loop he stamp on the screen all goods how hidden it?